Is it a good idea to modify linux driver for asix ax88279(without data sheet) to receive hardware time stamps for every ethernet packet
I was searching for USB to Ethernet Adapter that supports PTP with an external clock and also is able to h/w time stamp NON PTP Packets with its own clock. We need this for capturing packets with high precision and also do synchronisation using PTP / IEEE 1588.
We did find such a hardware that supports PTP synchronization: https://www.asix.com.tw/en/product/USBEthernet/Super-Speed_USB_Ethernet/AX88279
sadly, after a short discussion with their techincal support , they informed that AX88279 will only record timestamps when it detects PTP protocol packets. For normal packet formats, timestamps cannot be recorded.
I was also able to locate a github source for this driver on Linux.
https://github.com/ntonnaett/asix-usb-nic-linux-driver
And as i understand this driver on github doesnt support hardware time stamping for non PTP packets, therefore i was wondering if its a good idea  to extend the driver to support hardware time stamping for every packet.
The problem is , While i do believe it should be possible,
but as i dont have any data sheet from Asix informing me about register address and internal modules and
in addition to that, there is no official demo code or source code from Asix for this component,
therefore i completely rely on understading the implementation on github and extending it there on.  Is it a good idea or is it just walking into a lot of issues , due to my lack of understanding of linux kernel?
